# android studio FirebaseAuth (IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null)

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, crash, runtime-error

im working on my first project 
i used FirebaseAuth and firebase realtime database
i followed every step carefully at first everything is alright and my project has connect to the db successfully(two weeks ago) i had even test my db , but after i update my android studio version something went wrong :(
my app keep crash every time i click on the buttons. 
i really don't know what is the problem? before everything was alright
"i read articles about the api-key and i checked it there is nothing wrong with it"

here is my register code :

```
package com.example.lastone;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.santalu.maskedittext.MaskEditText;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.AwesomeValidation;
import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.ValidationStyle;
import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.utility.RegexTemplate;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class Register2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    MaskEditText license,phone;
    private EditText email,pass1,pass2;
    private   Button but;
    AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation;
    private  FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    //realtime
    DatabaseReference reference;
    //authinicate
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register2);
        //validation
        awesomeValidation=new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);
        updateUI();
        //authinication
        firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        license=findViewById(R.id.license);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        phone=findViewById(R.id.phone);
        pass1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass1);
        pass2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass2);
        but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
        String regexPassword = "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\d])(?=.*[~`!@#\\$%\\^&\\*\\(\\)\\-_\\+=\\{\\}\\[\\]\\|\\;:\"<>,./\\?]).{8,}";
        String Regex = ("[0-9]{10}");

        awesomeValidation.addValidation(Register2.this,R.id.license, Regex, R.string.licensee);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(Register2.this,R.id.email,android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS, R.string.emailrr);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(Register2.this,R.id.phone, RegexTemplate.TELEPHONE, R.string.phonen);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(Register2.this,R.id.pass1,regexPassword,R.string.pass11);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(Register2.this,R.id.pass2,R.id.pass1,R.string.pass22);


        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
        {
            signUp();
           // send to the database
            rootNode= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference=rootNode.getReference("users");

            //get all the values from the textfield

            String License =license.getText().toString();
            String Phone_number =phone.getText().toString();
            String Email =email.getText().toString();
            String password =pass1.getText().toString();

            UserHelperClass helper=new UserHelperClass(License , Phone_number, Email, password);
            reference.child(License).setValue(helper);

            //validate
            if(awesomeValidation.validate())
            {
                Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "Data Received Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
        }

    private void signUp() {
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), pass1.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            String email=user.getEmail();
                            String name=user.getDisplayName();
                            Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "Name : "+name+"\n"+"Email : "+email,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent=new Intent(Register2.this,Login.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

login code:

```
package com.example.lastone;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity
{
     private EditText email,pass;
     private Button lo;
     private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        lo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.lo);
        firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        lo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Signin();
            }
        });
    }
    private void Signin()
    {

        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            String email=user.getEmail();
                            String name=user.getDisplayName();
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Logged in successuly",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           // Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this,profile.class);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

error:

```
2020-04-04 02:25:41.923 7642-7642/com.example.lastone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lastone, PID: 7642
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:205)
        at com.example.lastone.Login.Signin(Login.java:53)
        at com.example.lastone.Login.access$000(Login.java:27)
        at com.example.lastone.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:46)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

also build gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lastone"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.santalu:mask-edittext:1.0.2'
}
```

the deadline is on this week please help :((

Comment: *NOTE* it only crashes when the fields are empty , if i try to submit and my fields are empty it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependencies and run your your projet again

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.3'
```

Comment: still the same,